# why can't I get greyed out objects in the outliner to show in Blender 2.8?

Tags: viewport, blender

I was working on an avatar project for a friend of mine, on my personal laptop using the 2.79b package of Blender because my GPU isn't strong enough for 2.8. 
He let me use his laptop to work on the project after realizing this and I started from scratch in hopes of 2.8 being better, but the same ZIP file I extracted from now has greyed out objects and won't appear in ANY viewport. I consulted lots of online resources to find an answer to why I can't get them to appear again but it's not working. The only objects visible are the ones that aren't greyed out.

[here's a screenshot of the outliner](https://i.stack.imgur.com/srNCI.png)

also, the greyed out ones are NOT hidden as you can see the V4_Arms_V3 object is greyed out, but set to visible, but not visible in any view. the V4_Arms_Human is also greyed out, set to visible in the viewport, but not visible in any window regardless of the Alt+H keystroke.

please help, I am completely lost here. 
(also the version of the app I'm having issues on is **2.82.7**)

Answer (score 0):

there is a small button hidden in the outliner that looks like a screen with a box inside it. enabling that setting and activating them for each of the objects will allow you so see your objects again!